# Validation error messages not displayed

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I set validation on an entity. 
When I test it, validation errors are in the profiler with the right message but I can't make them displayed on the webpage.
I can't find where I'm wrong.

My entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PACES\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"tutore"="Tutore","tuteur"="Tuteur", "admin"="Admin"})
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email"}, entityClass=User::class,
 *     message="L'adresse mail est déjà utilisée. Veuillez vérifier que vous n'êtes pas déjà inscrit. Si ce n'est pas le
cas, entrez une adresse mail différente.")
 */
abstract class User extends BaseUser
{
    ...
}
```

Twig :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
{%endif%}
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Profiler : 
[image]

Comment: Are the errors displayed in the **source** of the html? It could be just a style issue (ie if you are using bootstrap4)

Comment: The error div is there but it's empty.

Comment: When I remove `{{ form_errors(form) }}, errors are displayed just above each field. But I want them at the top of the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all errors to be on the general form and not in the fields you should set `'error_bubling' => true` in every fields of your formType

[From the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling): If true, any errors for this field will be passed to the parent field or form. For example, if set to true on a normal field, any errors for that field will be attached to the main form, not to the specific field.